# Se me desordena la tabla con el efecto Hover

Tags: html, css

Estoy buscando pasar el mouse encima de una imagen y que ésta se agrande (aumentando el `width` y `height`) pero cuando esto pasa, las otras imágenes y la tabla en la que están contenidas se mueven.

Quiero que se agrande la imagen con el `hover` pero que la tabla y la otras imágenes queden estáticas.

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
}

td{
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
}


.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft {
    object-position: left top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: width .5s height .5s; 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0;
}

.imagenPruebaTopRight {
    object-position: right top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomLeft {
    object-position: left bottom;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomRight {
    object-position: left bottom;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft:hover {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imagenPruebaTopRight:hover {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomLeft:hover {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomRight:hover {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CUIT / DNI</th>
                    <th>Número de pedido</th>
                    <th>Pedido Sap</th>
                    <th>Imágenes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <img class="imagenPruebaTopLeft" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba1.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaTopRight" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba2.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaBottomLeft" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba3.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaBottomRight" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba4.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo ideal para este caso es usar la función "scale()": https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Si te fijas, lo que hace es aumentar proporcionalmente el tamaño del elemento, sin afectar a los elementos colindantes. Es como meterle una lupa al elemento en sí. ;)

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
}

td{
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
}


.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft {
    object-position: left top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: width .5s height .5s; 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0;
}

.imagenPruebaTopRight {
    object-position: right top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomLeft {
    object-position: left bottom;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomRight {
    object-position: left bottom;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft:hover, .imagenPruebaTopRight:hover, .imagenPruebaBottomLeft:hover, .imagenPruebaBottomRight:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CUIT / DNI</th>
                    <th>Número de pedido</th>
                    <th>Pedido Sap</th>
                    <th>Imágenes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <img class="imagenPruebaTopLeft" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba1.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaTopRight" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba2.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaBottomLeft" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba3.jpg"/>
                            <img class="imagenPruebaBottomRight" src="~/ImgAndroid/Prueba4.jpg"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Uhh genial mil gracias! Por la respuesta y por cómo hacer el css más prolijo! Yo ya estaba buscando el scss.